# retrieving user input in code igniter but not getting the value inside a foreach loop

Tags: codeigniter, foreach

I am working with code igniter and got stuck when i compare the user input with the already existing values in database. I have a form from where i get a user input. The form is as follows:

```
       <form method="post" action="my_controller/my_method">
        <label>Mark :</label>
         <input type="text" name="avg_mark"><br>
        <label> Message </label>
         <input type="text" name = "message"><br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="send message">
       </form>
```

In my_controller/my_method

```
function my_method{
 $avg_mark =$this->input->post('avg_mark');
 $message = $this->input->post('message');
 echo $avg_mark;
}
```

when i echo $avg_mark iam getting the value. But problem arises when i take that value inside a foreach loop.

```
foreach($students as $row){
  echo $avg_mark;
 }
```

the page is blank and shows nothing which means iam not getting the input value inside the loop. And i tried this too inside the loop. Still the result is same.

```
foreach($students as $row){
   echo $this->input->post('avg_mark');
 }
```

What should i do to get the value inside a foreach loop.

Comment: what is the value of $students ?

Comment: $students is an array from database.$students   =   $this->my_model->get_students($class_id);

Comment: if there is no data in the $students variable, foreach wont execute so it wont display any result

Comment: check whether data is passing in the $student variable by using `print_r()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check that variable empty or not. Then you pass it in to foreach loop:-

```
if (!empty($students)) {
    foreach($students as $row){
        echo $avg_mark;
    }
}
```

Comment: yep, i was getting a null array. now its working. Thanks for all the comments and answer :)